# Customizing Google Form Responses in the Related Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have been searching for a simple solution to this for a while and cannot seem to come up with anything. I am relatively new to googledocs but I think I have done my homework on this one.

I am aiming to use a *form* to gather data via Yes or No questions. I then am looking to store the data as 1s and 0s (N=0 Y=1) in order to do some statistics. This may be solved by a simple script to convert the strings which are imported from the form in the spreadsheet and I am still working on this... However I wonder if I am not missing a simpler solution or setting with the form that would just send back a 1 or a 0 and not a Yes or No in string format.

Any ideas on a simple scale-able solution for this conversion from yes/no to 1/0 would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a Google Forms feature to do that, but a Google Apps Script triggered [on form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) can easily do it. Have you taken a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms has a question type of "Scale" that you could use, and avoid the translation step altogether.

[image: Screenshot]

Users could select a scale from "No" (0) to "Yes" (1), and your spreadsheet would end up containing the number.

### [image: Screenshot]

Note: There is a bug (some would say feature) with Scale questions currently. While you can choose to start a scale from 0, you cannot end it at 1; so 2 is the lowest maximum. You could still interpret 0 as No, but treat x > 0 as Yes.